# Need modem for a line-bonded ADSL2+ connection

Tags: networking, modem, adsl, adsl2+, vdsl

I have two semi-related questions:

What do I look for in specs to identify ADSL2+ modems capable of supporting line-bonding? I can't seem to locate any clear indication of those which do versus those which don't.

**Update 1**: ITU G998.2 seems to be the standard relevant to ADSL line-bonding. Is that usually mentioned in the advertising of qualifying modems?

---

Regarding a prospective VDSL connection, the distance from the ISP telephone exchange to my home is 1.6 KM as the bird flies. Is it likely I can get near the advertised speeds of 10mbps down/5mbps up based on physics alone? The ISP have no CPEs for rent at the moment, and the market availability is close to nil, except for Asus DSL-N66U. That's an expensive modem. I want to know if VDSL can deliver at that distance befoe I buy the modem and apply for a VDSL connection. My research did not yield unambiguous answers.

**Update 2**: I had an ADSL2+ - 2mbps Down/0.5mbps Up - connection installed using an ISP-rented modem. The downstream SNR is in the mid-30s, while the upstream is 42 dB. The line attenuation downstream is 19.8 dB while upstream is 7.6 dB. Can VDSL viabiity of 10 down/5 up be inferred from these numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically any modem connected to a router that supports bonding will do (or a Linux computer with multiple NICs). It's kinda strange that they don't do SDSL instead though.

Comment: So there's no "line-bonded" modem as such?

Comment: It's a modem/router combo that supports bonding.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. I think "line bonding" is done in the modem and bonds the two lines to form a single channel at a lower level than the router operates.

Comment: Right, so what should I search for or look for to identify a modem as line-bonding ready?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but may as well answer it. Anecdotally line bonding never seemed all that successful, we never bothered with it much.

> The line attenuation downstream is 19.8 dB while upstream is 7.6 dB.
>   Can VDSL viabiity of 10 down/5 up be inferred from these numbers?

We can get an idea, but will need some more background to be sure. ~20dB dAtten on ADSL points to around 1400m of a run and an ADSL line that should manage 15Mb or more on ADSL2+ (closer to 20 in good conditions). To know what you'd get for VDSL there are two factors we need to know. One, are you getting VDSL from a street cab(closer than the exchange itself) or from the the same racks as your ADSL. Two, does your telco use g.vectoring? That gives a nice big range boost.

Conservatively, going on exchange based VDSL with no vectoring you're talking around 12_1(DS_US) but maybe 15_3, being very conservative. Thats based 17A annex, the "better" annexes use almost twice as much spectrum and can give you a chunk more. Cab launched and you'd be a lot closer and a lot faster.

In any case your teclo should be able to pre-rate lines and give you rough guidelines.